# Verify/Add PDF Signatures with iText7

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I need to port a Java program that used iText5 for PDF signature verification/creation to iText7.

The old code obviously does not work as-is, as much of iText was restructured.

All examples and tutorials that I found on how to do this are for iText5.
So does the (excellent) [white paper](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security/digital-signatures-white-paper/digital-signatures-chapter-5). They rely on the `PdfReader` returning a list of `AcroFields` via the `getAcroFields()` method, on which all signature-related operations are executed.

In iText7, the `PdfReader` does not have that method anymore.

Does anybody know of examples/documentation on this for iText7?

Comment: Several of the white paper samples have been ported to itext 7, cf. the iText7 samples artifact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the ported samples of the White Paper on our repository:

https://github.com/itext/i7js-signatures/tree/develop/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/signatures

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed!

Comment: The above url is no longer valid. The samples can be found here now: https://github.com/itext/i7js-samples

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I edited my answer to link to github instead.

Comment: those URLs re no longer valid. Any ideas where are they now?

Comment: @EnriqueMolinari I do have an idea! I'll update my answer.