# Add Digital Signature to a PDF using IText 7

Tags: itext, itext7

For IText 5, adding digital signature was fairly easy.
The link for its documentation is:
http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security/digital-signatures-white-paper/digital-signatures-chapter-2

Can someone share the link to documentation for doing so in ITEXT 7?
I have tried various ways to no avail. Could not find any links online. I can unsign and check signature, but can't add it.

Comment: Have you had a look at the [iText 7 Java samples github repository](https://github.com/itext/i7js-samples)? In the subfolder [/publications/signatures/](https://github.com/itext/i7js-samples/tree/develop/publications/signatures) it contains the whitepaper samples ported to iText 7.

Comment: Thank you so much. If you can write the answer below, ill mark it :)

Comment: @mkl the link does not exists anymore.... any idea where is it now?

Comment: Found it... https://github.com/itext/i7js-signatures/tree/develop/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/signatures/chapter02

Comment: @EnriqueMolinari Thanks, I updated the links in my answer below.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37647359/1729265

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ports of the Digital Signatures Whitepaper code examples to iText 7 can be found in the [iText 7 Java signature samples github repository](https://github.com/itext/i7js-signatures) test sources package [com.itextpdf.samples.signatures](https://github.com/itext/i7js-signatures/tree/develop/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/signatures), e.g. an excerpt from the simple [C2_01_SignHelloWorld](https://github.com/itext/i7js-signatures/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/signatures/chapter02/C2_01_SignHelloWorld.java) example:

```
public void sign(String src, String dest,
                 Certificate[] chain,
                 PrivateKey pk, String digestAlgorithm, String provider,
                 PdfSigner.CryptoStandard subfilter,
                 String reason, String location)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    // Creating the reader and the signer
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest), false);
    // Creating the appearance
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.getSignatureAppearance()
            .setReason(reason)
            .setLocation(location)
            .setReuseAppearance(false);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(36, 648, 200, 100);
    appearance
            .setPageRect(rect)
            .setPageNumber(1);
    signer.setFieldName("sig");
    // Creating the signature
    IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
    IExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
    signer.signDetached(digest, pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, subfilter);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add signature to pdf using public key(not private key)?

Comment: @Banzragch.B *"Is it possible to add signature to pdf using public key"* - That would make no sense, would it? Such a signature is meant to ensure that a specific person applied it, no one else. Thus, it must be generated using some *private* data, not merely a public key.

Comment: In principle, though, often key pairs can be used inversely. I.e. one can often technically create a "signature" using a public key, but to verify that signature one needs the private key. This merely makes no sense, see my previous comment.

Comment: i mean the signature has been signed by private key(other service does it) and i have certificate chain. I just need to add signature to existing pdf and do validition. Do you have any advise?

Comment: So you want to add a second signature? Or something different altogether? You probably should make this an actual stack overflow question instead of a series of some comments here. In that question you could explain in more detail what your use case is.

Comment: thank you for quick reply, i will add question then put the link here.

Comment: Can you please see my case here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60312185/verify-digital-signature-using-certificate-chain-in-java